# Gradient background for PDF

Tags: xsl-fo

Is there any way to add my PDF a gradient background using FO? It could be background image as well, doesn't matter. But I would like to add to the page, not just to the body region.

Answer (score 4):

Certainly. On would create an SVG image that matches what they want for the gradient. For this example, I am using a linear gradient from yellow to red, left to right.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.0" height="1in" width="8.5in">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
            <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,0);stop-opacity:1" />
            <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0);stop-opacity:1" />
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <rect width="8.5in" height="1in" fill="url(#grad1)" />
</svg>
```

Then, insert that as the background image for the region-before of the page and set the extent of the page to the full height of the page:

```
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    font-family="Times" font-size="16px">
    <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="backgrad" page-width="8.5in" page-height="11in">
            <fo:region-body/>
            <fo:region-before extent="11in" background-image="backgrad.svg"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
    </fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="backgrad">
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
            <fo:block>
                Hello
            </fo:block>
        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

The result is this:

[image]

Comment: What FO Processor are you using?

Comment: I tested that with RenderX XEP and Apache FOP 1.1, works for both.

Comment: Thanks. I'm gonna try, but I've already found a way using background image. **<fo:block-container position="fixed" top="0" left="0"><fo:block><fo:external-graphic src="image.jpg" /></fo:block></fo:block-container>**

Comment: Certainly that will work, but only for a one page document. Unless you are putting that in a repeated region that will be on every page.